# How to add django back-end after making a frontend website with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, reactjs

I made the front-end of my website with the Materialize framework and ReactJS to make it dynamic.
My goal is to make a upvote/downvote system so I need a back-end ORM to use with a database.

I decided to go with Django as I'm more experienced with python, but when I was following a tutorial, I did the command:
`npx create-react-app frontend`
with the intention of replacing the new files with my "homemade frontend" to make it work except the directory structures were completely different.

**Tree made with the command:**

```
├── frontend
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── manifest.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.css
│   │   ├── App.js
│   │   ├── App.test.js
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   └── registerServiceWorker.js
```

**My original frontend tree:**

```
├── frontend
│   ├── Components
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   ├── materialize.css
│   │   └── materialize.min.css
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── init.js
│   │   ├── materialize.js
│   │   └── materialize.min.js
│   ├── src
│   │   └── word_card.js
```

I feel like the new version of my frontend is based with the idea of making everything with ReactJS in opposition with my old one which only has ReactJS as a supplement.

How do I use django as a backend in this case?

Thanks a lot for taking of your time to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are now following a React with Django tutorial, but you have become stuck because the structure of the React app in the tutorial is different to the structure you have already created.

The way that you use Django is the same in either case. You are making a decoupled application with separation of concerns between the front and back end. Django doesn't know or care how your front end is structured.

If you are new to Django I would suggest you start by following the official Django tutorial and then move on to the official Django REST framework tutorial.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/